# Autotouch iPhone lua Tap position with 2 variables

Tags: iphone, lua, autotouch

There a command call "tap(x,y)" and I need a way to combine a row variable and a column variable

The code:

```
--[[ Row Pos ]]--
r1 = 587.95
r2 = 383.05
--[[ Barracks Column ]]--
cb1 = 476.53
cb2 = 722.26

--[[ Barracks Variable ]]--
wizard = "r2" .. "," .. "cb1"
healer = "r2" .. "," .. "cb2"

tap(healer);
usleep(30000)
tap(wizard);
usleep(30000);
```

Error:

```
Bad Argument #2 to 'touchdown' (number expected, got string)
```

Which means it wants number but I'm inputting string is there a different way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to combine the two variables in one string. Just use the column and row variables:

```
-- Row Pos
r1 = 587.95
r2 = 383.05
-- Barracks Column
cb1 = 476.53
cb2 = 722.26

-- wizard
tap(cb1, r2) -- did you mean r1? I just used your example
usleep(30000)
-- healer
tap(cb2, r2)
usleep(30000)
```

Note the the column (x) is given first.

Some comments on your code: it is not necessary to end one-line comments, as can be seen in my example. Furthermore, the semicolon is not needed, i omitted it.

If you wanted to use a variable collecting both arguments, you could use a table and unpack it:

```
local wizard = { cb1, r2 } -- { x, y }
tap(table.unpack(wizard))
```

You could now use a wrapper for the function `tap`, adding syntactic sugar:

```
local old_tap = tap
function tap(location)
    old_tap(table.unpack(location))
end
```

To go even further, check the argument and call the function the right way:

```
local old_tap = tap
function tap(x, y)
    if type(x) == "table" then
        old_tap(table.unpack(x))
    else
        old_tap(x, y)
    end
end
-- now tap can be used both ways:
tap(cb1, r2) -- wizard
local healer = { cb2, r2 }
tap(healer)
```

Comment: Is there a way I could use a name variable like wizard with both the column and the row

Comment: Thank you the functions I'm not very good at and I can read that function really easily so thank you